# Function returning list is showing False python

Tags: python, list, split

I'm a newbie here, and I am trying to make python recognizes the .split() list inside another. It's a little bit hard to explain, so I will show it:

```
>>>   #this is a function that separates the last word in the string, spliting the string by words and then transforming it into a list and the using the len() to know what is the position of the last item in the list, so that I can return it to another var.

>>> def lastWord(phrase):
       phrase = list(phrase.split()[len(list(phrase.split()))-1:]))
       return phrase

>>> x = "Hello World"
>>> d = lastWord(x)
>>> d
['World']
>>> x.split()
['Hello', 'World']
>>> one_list ["Hello", "World", "Anything"]
>>> one_list
['Hello', 'World', 'Anything']
>>> x.split() in one_list
False
>>> list(x.split()) in one_list
False
>>> d in one_list
False
```

How can I make it recognize the generated split list, created using .split() inside another list??

Comment: Are you trying to check `d[0] in one_list`? Also, note that `[len(list(phrase.split()))-1:]` is just `[-1:]`, and the call to `list` is redundant, as is the temporary assignment to `phrase`, and... why does `lastWord` return a list anyway?

Comment: a list cannot be in a list of strings

Comment: I was seeing further, and I've noted python doesn't recognize a list inside another, just strings. So I can't find x = ["Hello"] inside one_list = ["Hello", "World"]. x has to be just "Hello", and not ["Hello"]. Thats it. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

Problem because you are trying to find ['Hello', 'World'] in ["Hello", "World", "Anything"]

Will give you True when

```
one_list = [["Hello", "World"], "Anything"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the following -

```
x.split() in one_list
```

to -

```
exists = True
for item in x.split():
    if item not in one_list:
        exists = False
        break
print exists
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "in" like that to test for each individual item:

```
x.split() in one_list
```

Try with this:

```
all(x in one_list for x in x.split())
```